# How to count how many inputs collect this function?

Tags: jquery

How to count how many inputs collect this function and if is not 4 then displays alert with some information?

```
 $('#dialog').on('show', function () {
        $('form#form_save_account input:visible').each(function(idx, $input) {
            $('#dialog .bank-data .' +  $input.name + ' .value').text($input.value);
        });
    });
```

Comment: By "inputs", do you mean "arguments"?

Comment: Yes. Form input (this are arguments in this case)

Comment: Oh sorry, then I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: I was wondering, do you only want to know how many input elements are matched by the selector expression, or do you also want to check that their values aren't empty? I updated my answer again to reflect both cases.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to check how many elements are found by your selector expression, You could use the `length` property, which is defined on jQuery objects:

```
$('#dialog').on('show', function () {
    var inputs = $('form#form_save_account input:visible');

    if (inputs.length != 4) {
        // Handle error
    }

    // Further work
}
```

If you also want to make sure that each `input` element has a non-empty value, you could filter the `inputs` variable before checking the length:

```
inputs = inputs.filter(function(i, input) { 
    return $(input).val().trim() != ""; 
});
```

You might also want to have a look at the jQuery form validation plugin, as it can automate such tasks:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

**Edit:** Modified as I misunderstood your question in the beginning. Also added some more information.

Answer (score -1):

```
var index = 0 
$('#dialog').on('show', function () {
    $('form#form_save_account input:visible').each(function(idx, $input) {
        index += 1;
    });
    if (index !== 4) { // do alert }
});
```

Comment: -1 Downside of this: The error message will only be shown after all elements have been processed (and thus the DOM was already modified). Additionally, the OP wanted exactly 4 elements, not at least.

Comment: How is it going to be processed when the iterator just counts the index? No need to down vote.

Comment: Oh I was assuming you intended to have the original loop body in there as well. Sorry.

Comment: But aside from that, I consider it bad code. Why loop over the set of matched elements twice, if there is a lengthbproperty? http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: Bad code? They do EXACTLY the same thing just a different approach. I figured he's in the loop already,so might as well adapt to what code he has written already. jQuery just behind the scenes loops through the matched object. If you're using jQuery, are you mandated to use it for everyday JavaScript functions just because it's there?

Comment: He/she cannot include it in the existing loop: As I said, that would cause the DOM to be partially updated before the error is reported. Therefore he/she needs two consecutive loops with your approach. Which is harder to read, as the intention is not immediately visible.

Comment: What jQuery does internally is not relevant - if I use all the functionality it offers instead of my own, the code becomes more concise and idiomatic, and thus easier to understand for others (and me).